# Ubuntu 17.04 alongside windows boots into grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

yesterday I installed Ubuntu 17.04 alongside windows. When I chose to boot ubuntu I could choose between ubuntu and windows in menu. But today when I booted into ubuntu, instead of menu I went to grub command line.

When I try `ls` there is no directory containing linux booting files. Do I have to reinstall ubuntu? What will happen with a space that was allocated for the first installation?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: @Redbob -- not a duplicate of that question but maybe another. OP doesn't have a problem installing. He deleted his partition.

Answer (score 0):

Did Win10 update? the Windows 10 Creators update deletes Linux partitions.

Boot a LiveCD or similar media. `testdisk` shoud be installed.
If not type `sudo apt-get install testdisk'

Then use `testdisk to recover the deleted partitions.

In most cases the recovery is all that is needed for a normal boot.

Comment: No I have had creators update installed before.

Actually I think I f*cked it myself. I allocated free space in windows before ubuntu installation, after I installed ubuntu and was there, I went back to windows, checked disk partion and it was still labeled as unallocated space so I merged it back with main disk space. Could this delete ubuntu?

Comment: the data on the disk isn't erased, just the partition information is changed. It is still possible to recover the partitions with testdisk. Note: Windows can not read ext partitions without special drivers being added (if they are available)

Comment: Ok I will try testdisk. If that won't work I will reinstall. I did not have any data there yet. Thank you @ravery

Comment: if there is nothing important there, then reinstalling is easiest, and doesn't risk the windows partition

Comment: ok I will reinstall just for sure.